# I am looking for toolkits/extensions for Universal windows 10 apps for plotting/charts

Tags: visual-studio, plot, charts, windows-10, toolkit

The title says it all. In the XAML toolbox I am only able to use the XAML controls (those located in universal windows components tab) and no other, but there is no chart of any sort availible. So, I am interested if there is anyone who found any free 3rd party toolkits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the winrt toolkit that contains a free charting control.

https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

It also contains many other useful controls.